# Function for looping over common variable names with different suffixes in R

Tags: r, loops

I have some code which I'm looking to replicate many times, each for a different country as the suffix.

Assuming 3 countries as a simple example:

```
country_list <- c('ALB', 'ARE', 'ARG')
```

I'm trying to create a series of variables called `a_m5_ALB`, `a_m5_ARE`, `a_m5_ARG` etc which have various functions e.g. `addcol` or `round_df` applied to `reg_math_ALB`, `reg_math_ARE`, `reg_math_ARG` etc

```
for (i in country_list) {
 
  paste("a_m5", i , sep = "_")  <- addcol(paste("reg_math", i , sep = "_"))

}

for (i in country_list) {
 
  paste("a_m5", i , sep = "_")  <- round_df(paste("reg_math", i , sep = "_"))

}
```

where `addcol` and `round_df`  are defined as:

```
addcol = function(y){
    dat1 = mutate(y, p.value = ((1 - pt(q = abs(reg.t.value), df = dof))*2))
    return(dat1)
}

round_df <- function(x, digits) {
    numeric_columns <- sapply(x, mode) == 'numeric'
    x[numeric_columns] <-  round(x[numeric_columns], digits)
    x
}
```

The loop errors when any of the functions are added in brackets before the paste variable part but it works if doing it manually e.g.

`a_m5_ALB <- addcol(reg_math_ALB)`

Please could you help? I think it's the application of the function in a loop which i'm getting wrong.

Errors:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Error in round(x[numeric_columns], digits) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Thank you

Comment: Manipulating variable names directly is always painful. You should consider if you could get the same result with a named list: `reg_math[["ALG"]] <- "some_value"` then you can directly use `lapply` or `map`.

Comment: there is this new function in dplyr called rename_with, you just need to define the function and you can rename whatever you need with it

Comment: Bruno: `rename_with()` only renames columns inside a dataframe. Here ormiz is apparently trying to rename the whole objects (which is probably not the easiest way to do that task).

Answer (score 1):

From your examples, you're really in a case where everything should be in a single dataframe. Here, keeping separate variables for each country is not the right tool for the job. Say you have your per-country dataframes saved as csv, you can rewrite everything as:

```
library(tidyverse)
country_list <- c('ALB', 'ARE', 'ARG') 

read_data <- function(ctry){
  read_csv(paste0("/path/to/file/", "reg_math_", ctry)) %>%
  add_column(country = ctry)
}

total_df <- map_dfr(country_list, read_data)

total_df %>%
  mutate(p.value = (1 - pt(q = abs(reg.t.value), df = dof))*2) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = digits))
```

And it gives you immediate access to all other `dplyr` functions that are great for this kind of manipulation.